# connect mysql link to bootstrap button

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, button, hyperlink

I've made a button, here is the piece of code (bootstrap):

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Download</a>
```

And this piece of mysql code, which contains a few links:

```
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","admin133","kernel");
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
     echo "Error bij connecten: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }

   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM hack ORDER BY ID DESC  ");

   echo "<table border='0'>
   <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Status</th>
   <th>Retepreter</th>
   <th>Kwikie</th>
   <th>Nevermind</th>
   </tr>";

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['kakatoeee'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['kakatoe2'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['kakatoe'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['papaja'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     }
   echo "</table>";

   mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

Now, my question is, how do I make it so that the links connect to the bootstrap buttons? (Sorry if I'm a bit unclear, I'm Dutch an it's pretty hard to type in English)

papaja, kakatoe etc. is my http!

Comment: echo "<td>" . $row['kakatoe'] . "</td>";

kakatoe is my http